# Return null value, if node not present in RSS-feed (ampscript)

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, xml, rss

I am trying to populate an e-mail with 5 images and text using ampscript and a RSS-feed.

The RSS looks like this:

```
<title>title</title>
<link>foo.com</link>
<enclosure height="638" length="123028" type="image/jpeg" url="imageurl.jpg" width="960"/>
<category>bar category</category>
</item>
```

The "enclosure"-node is the source for the images is not always present, so I am trying to figure out a way to skip that item in the for-loop.

Here is my amscript (trimmed down to the basics):

```
%%[ 

var @xml
set @xml = httpget(xmlfeed.rss)
set @test = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/enclosure",0)

var @i, @maxToDisplay, @nodes, @test, @rows, @rowCount

set @test = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/enclosure",0)
set @nodes = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/*",0)
set @maxToDisplay = 5

If RowCount(@test) >= @maxToDisplay THEN
    set @rowCount = @maxToDisplay 
ELSE
    SET @rowCount = RowCount(@test) 
ENDIF

for @i = 1 to @rowCount do 

   set @imageurl = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat("//item[",@i,"]/enclosure"),0),1),'url_att',0) 

]%%
```

When the enclosure-node is not present I get the following error-message:

> Invalid index (parameter 2) passed to Row function. Index must be less
>   than or equal to the row count.  Index Value: 1  Row Count: 0

I've tried reviewing the ampscript documentation for all functions, which is why the Field-function has a second parameter of 0, which should return a null value on error. However, this is not the case here.

I hope someone can help me figure out how to get ampscript to return a null value, if the node is not present. Ultimately, I am just interested in skipping an item, if the enclosure-node is not present.

Thanks,
Emil

Answer (score 1):

Since you're dealing with rowsets, you'll need to utilize [**rowcount()**](https://ampscript.guide/book/rowcount) to check for results.

Here's [**my go-to boilerplate**](https://gist.github.com/wvpv/cc72b3662c43ba2c1650cccc979ee137) for parsing XML.  The conditionals after the `@nodepath` assignment is the part pertinent to your question:

```
%%[

var @xml, @isXML, @nodes, @rowCount
set @xml = AttributeValue("xml")

if indexOf(@xml,"<cart>") > 0 then

  set @nodes = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"/cart/items/item",0)
  set @rowCount = rowcount(@nodes)

  if @rowCount > 0 then

    for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

      var @nodepath 
      var @sku
      var @name
      var @url

      set @nodepath = concat("/cart/items/item[",@i,"]/")

      if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"sku"))) > 0 then
          set @sku = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"sku"),0),1),'Value')
      endif

      if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"name"))) > 0 then
          set @name = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"name"),0),1),'Value')
      endif

      if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"url"))) > 0 then
          set @url = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"url"),0),1),'Value')
      endif

      if not empty(@sku) and not empty(@name) and not empty(@url) then

      ]%%

       <br><a href="%%=redirectto(@url)=%%">%%=v(@sku)=%%</a> - <a href="%%=redirectto(@url)=%%">%%=v(@name)=%%</a>

      %%[

      endif

    next @i

  else

   outputline(concat("<br>no products found"))

  endif

else

  outputline(concat("<br>no XML found"))

endif

]%%
```